# Java Script slideshow won't display slides

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have coded this JavaScript slideshow to display a number of images however they are not displayed anywhere, the only thing showing are the two buttons I have included for choosing slides.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x= document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```html
        <img class="slides" href="Bgimage.jpg">
        <img class="slides" href="roses.jpg">
        <img class="slides" href="sunflowers.jpg">
        <img class="slides" href="Vessel1.jpg">
        <button class="go-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094</button>
        <button class="go-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095</button>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the [`src` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp), not the `href` one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Img` tag has `src` not `href`. Your code works perfectly.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x= document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```html
<img class="slides" src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/">
        <img class="slides" src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/ff0000/">
        <img class="slides" src="http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/ff0000/000">
        <img class="slides" src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/ff0000/">
        <button class="go-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094</button>
        <button class="go-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [img](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) tag uses **src** to determine the source of the image. If you change **href** to **src**, you should be able to see the images again.

```
<img class="slides" src="Bgimage.jpg">
<img class="slides" src="roses.jpg">
<img class="slides" src="sunflowers.jpg">
<img class="slides" src="Vessel1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showDivs(slideIndex);
function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x= document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n >= x.length) { slideIndex = 0; }
    if (n < 0) { slideIndex = x.length-1; }

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if(i!==slideIndex) {
          x[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
          x[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
        <img class="slides" src="Bgimage.jpg">
        <img class="slides" src="roses.jpg">
        <img class="slides" src="sunflowers.jpg">
        <img class="slides" src="Vessel1.jpg">
        <button class="go-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094</button>
        <button class="go-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095</button>
```